# Windows 7 windows explorer not finding known files

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I am using Windows 7 and the Windows explorer search function has stopped working on my local computer. I have rebuilt the index, checked the box for searching non-indexed locations, and tried to to restore to a previous restore point. Nothing has worked. I am able to search remote computers on the network, so it appears the problem is local. I am also able to use powershell to find files, but am assuming it uses a different search method.

I know this is not a lot to go on. I was able to fix it in the past by rebuilding, but not this time.

Any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to this folder,
c:\Users\Your name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\1033\
And delete the file StructuredQuerySchema.bin

Comment: I deleted the file but it did not solve the problem.